# Questions about The Missing Chapter of Clean Architecture by Robert Martin

Tags: fastapi, clean-architecture

I've just read `Clean Architecture` by Robert Martin and some questions about `The Missing Chapter` appeared.

When working with FastAPI+SQLAlchemy one need to create global engine, configure sessionmaker and create base model. This can look like this:

```
from logging import getLogger
from typing import Any, Callable, Optional

import orjson
from app.config import PROJECT_NAME, settings
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
from sqlalchemy.ext import asyncio as sa_asyncio
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncEngine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

logger = getLogger(__name__)


def get_master_dsn(is_test: bool = False):
    master_dsn = URL.create(
        drivername=settings.DB.PROTOCOL,
        username=settings.DB.USER,
        password=settings.DB.PASSWORD,
        host=settings.DB.HOST,
        port=settings.DB.PORT,
        database=settings.DB.DATABASE,
    ).render_as_string(hide_password=False)

    if is_test:
        master_dsn += "_test"

    return master_dsn


POSTGRESQL_MASTER_DSN = get_master_dsn()


def orjson_dumps(value: Any, *, default: Optional[Callable[[Any], Any]]) -> str:
    return orjson.dumps(value, default=default).decode()


def init_db(long_operation: bool = False, is_test: bool = False) -> AsyncEngine:
    dsn = get_master_dsn(is_test)

    timeout_command = (
        settings.DB.TIMEOUT_COMMAND * 100
        if long_operation
        else settings.DB.TIMEOUT_COMMAND
    )

    return sa_asyncio.create_async_engine(
        dsn,
        max_overflow=0,
        connect_args={
            "server_settings": {"application_name": PROJECT_NAME, "timezone": "utc"},
            "timeout": settings.DB.TIMEOUT_CONNECTION,
            "command_timeout": timeout_command,
        },
        pool_pre_ping=True,
        json_serializer=orjson_dumps,
        json_deserializer=orjson.loads,
    )


db = init_db()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=db, class_=sa_asyncio.AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)
metadata = MetaData(schema=settings.DB.SCHEMA)
Base = declarative_base(metadata=metadata)
```

Then developer should inherit `Base` model somewhere.

Before I ask questions let's see at the figure 36.4:

[image]

1. Where in this layout place the stuff about preparing database?
2. Where place SqlAlchemy models? Inside components in `models.py`?
3. Where or how store interfaces?
4. How the project structure can look like? Like this:

> ```
> web
> components
> - orders
> -- usecases
> -- models 
> -- utils
> - another_component
> ....
> ```

?

P.S. I remembered about `Main` component in chapter 26. It seems that this could be proper place?

Comment: Python doesn't really have interfaces, so no need to think about those. A common way is to either have `models/orders.py` or just a `models.py` with the model objects inside. Setting up and connecting to databases can be done as part of your app init in your `app.py` / `__init__.py` in the module, or in a separate file as `database.py`.

Comment: You should generally be more concerned about what the general concepts are (separation of responsibilities) instead of a particular directory/file layout - use the common structure for the language you're working with. Java and Python have different standard code standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing chapter was written by Simon Brown, who also gave a at the converence GOTO 2018 about modulare [monoliths](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OjqD-ow8GE&t=10s).

Even Simon talks about Java in "The missing chapter" it might also be applied to other languages as well. The main point is about modularization. When you write code that is accessible from anywhere, developers tend to use it everywhere. As a consequence they build a net of dependencies that make those code hard to maintain.

Therefore, Simon proposes to use the Java package scope modifier in order to modularize a system. The package scope, as the name implies, is only accessible from classes within the same package. So if you can make all classes that do not belong to the component's public API package scoped, you can prevent the dependency net.

As far as I know there is no package scope in python. So you have to think about alternatives that are applicable in your language in order to prevent a dependency net. I have implemented a [Java example](https://github.com/link-intersystems/clean-architecture-example) and published it on github that might help you too or others who come accross this post.

> Where in this layout place the stuff about preparing database?
> Where place SqlAlchemy models? Inside components in models.py?

Everything about the database is in the same package. Some developers might argue that this will lead to a lot of files in one folder and that this might be confusing. But there might be other ways to fix this. E.g. a package in Java must not reside in one jar. You can have the same package in multiple jars. So you can have different build units and separate the different aspects of the component in that way. Take y look at [my example code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OjqD-ow8GE&t=10s) Maybe there is an equivalent in python.

> Where or how store interfaces?

The same way you deal with the db stuff. Everything goes into the same package.

> How the project structure can look like? Like this:

```
web
 components
 - orders
 -- usecases
 -- models 
 -- utils
 - another_component
 ....
```

The project structure that you show will not be compliant with the package by component approach, because you separate by architectural aspects and not by component. Since the usecases have a dependency to models the models must be accessible from the usecases. So they are usually public scoped and therefore accessible from anywhere. A better approach would be a domain driven separation.

```
 components
 - orders
 - customer
 - products
 - ...
```

Like I said before... Some developers argue that this would lead to a lot of classes in one folder. But there might be other ways in your language to handle those situations.

If you take a look at [my example code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OjqD-ow8GE&t=10s) you will see that I separated the db stuff from the use cases by modules that use the same package.

[image: package by component exmample]

I know it is Java and you need a python solution. I don't have a lot of python knowledge, but hopefully this example still helps you or others to adapt the concept Simon Brown talks about to your language. Maybe these other will then post another answer that fits your needs.

**EDIT**

> 1. Is it common situation that an entity from one component is being requested from other component?

There are situations when the same entity is needed by two components. In DDD this is called a [shared kernel](https://vaadin.com/blog/ddd-part-1-strategic-domain-driven-design#_shared_kernel).

But usually one domain component is responsible for one part of the domain. Even the same term might exist in two different parts of the domain, it often has another meaning in the different parts. DDD calles a context in which a term has one meaning a [bounded context](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html).

> 2. if a component in clean architecture "spans all layers" why on a schema github.com/link-intersystems/clean-architecture-example/blob/… com.mycompany.myapp..web (controller) is not inside com.mycompany.myapp.orders component? it looks like that a component is combination request data - use case - output data...

Uncle Bob usually uses the term "details" when he talks about the web. The web is a detail and should be separated. This goes back to Ivar Jackobson who wrote the book [Object-Oriented Software Engineering - A Use Case Drivern Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201544350) back in 1992. The interessting part of the title is *A Use Case Driven Approach*. Ivar Jackobson puts the use cases in the center of an architecture. The architecture Ivar Jackobson describes in his book is called the BCE - boundary controller entity. A lot of other architectures also put the uses cases in the center like the clean architecture, hexagonal architecture or onion architecture. Use cases have implement the business logic and therefore have the most value. Thus all those architectures separate them from things that do not have a lot of business value. As a result you can easily exchange those details, like the ui or database. Either because of business needs or for tests.

Comment: Thanks for the Github repository link. 
1. Is it common situation that an entity from one component is being requested from other component?
2. if a component in clean architecture "spans all layers" why on a schema https://github.com/link-intersystems/clean-architecture-example/blob/main/src/site/resources/package-by-component.png com.mycompany.myapp..web (controller) is not inside com.mycompany.myapp.orders component? it looks like that a component is combination request data - use case - output data...

Comment: oh, yes, I forgot about repositories...